# Import After Effects Camera Motion into Blender?

Tags: animation, camera, import

I just got Adobe After Effects CC with Cinema 4D lite.  I use Blender for 3d animation and I don't want to switch to C4D. Is there any way to export After Effects camera movement to Blender?

Comment: You might have to write code...

Comment: You can export it to C4D, then to blender...

Answer (score 2):

There is a script by **Atom** that uses Javascript to accomplish this. The full thread to download, and very clear instructions on how to use it are [here in blenderartists.org](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?232032-After-Effects-To-Blender-2-70a-Javascript-Python-Generator&highlight=afterfx)

Comment: Script no longer works.

Comment: You could try exporting as FBX from blender and using a third party plugin to import the camera into AfterFX...