# Importing After Effects .aep file

Tags: import

Is there any procedure/plug-in to import .aep files into Blender?

Comment: Welcome Marius :) Which objects you want to export from AE? Null objects and the Camera? Please add more context to the question! Maybe this one helps: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?232032-After-Effects-To-Blender-2-70a-Javascript-Python-Generator&highlight=afterfx Enjoy, blender.se!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import After Effects Camera Motion into Blender?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14927/import-after-effects-camera-motion-into-blender)

Comment: I have a template.aep file and I want to edit/modify in Blender or other open source linux based