# importing .aep files in blender 2.79

Tags: import

I know someone asked this question... But mine is slightly different... I don't have after effects but I would like to use an .aep file (downloaded from internet) on Blender.. Is there a way I could do that?

Comment: No you can't import aep files into blender.

Comment: Duplicate of [Importing After Effects .aep file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35420/importing-after-effects-aep-file), but cannot be voted as there is no answer..