# Export AE Camera data to Blender?

Tags: camera

I use AE CC, and I would like to export my camera data from After Effects to Blender for a school project. I can involve Cinema4D if needed, but I want to do the bulk of the project in Blender. I did a bit of research, people have found out how to do this but it seems to only work in CS5.5

Comment: @cegaton I wouldn't consider it a duplicate, i'm asking for exporting from AE to blender, not blender to AE.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14927/import-after-effects-camera-motion-into-blender

Comment: @cegaton I am unable to download the files off of Atom's Blenderartist page: https://gyazo.com/762b1c3f554be8cab8bf6c8b5574ae0d

Comment: You need to login to blenderartists

Comment: @cegaton I am https://i.gyazo.com/1d4e396189fc8a577be6184a533d7441.gif

Comment: contact the moderators on that site

Comment: @cegaton I will do that, do you have access? If possible, and not breaking any rules, do you think you could upload that file to Dropbox or something? I don't have much more time to sort everything out before my school is over, and I won't be able to film anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40353/discussion-between-josh-silveous-and-cegaton).